# CASE checking expiration in select statement in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL `case` and I don't know what is my problem in my query. The error comes from update statement. And I don't know if my idea works. Thanks in advance.

This is my query

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN (date(au.expiration) < date(now()))
 THEN (UPDATE controller SET access = '0' WHERE idno = au.assignedidno)
 ELSE (UPDATE controller SET access = '1'  WHERE idno = au.assignedidno)
 END FROM assignuser au
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an UPDATE statement with a join of the 2 tables and setting the value to the column with a CASE expression:

```
UPDATE controller c 
INNER JOIN assignuser au
ON c.idno = au.assignedidno
SET c.access = CASE 
  WHEN (date(au.expiration) < date(now())) THEN '0'
  ELSE '1'
END
```

This can be simplified like this:

```
UPDATE controller c 
INNER JOIN assignuser au
ON c.idno = au.assignedidno
SET c.access = (date(au.expiration) >= date(now()))
```